# Retrieving multiple rows in SQL Server but distinct filtering only on one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.Name, Product.GroupID, Product.GradeID,
       AVG(tblReview.Grade) AS Grade
FROM   Product left Join tblReview ON Product.GroupID = tblReview.GroupID
WHERE  (Product.CategoryID = @CategoryID)
GROUP  BY Product.ProductID, Product.Name, Product.GroupID, Product.GradeID
```

I would like to return only the rows where Product.Name is unique. If I make a `SELECT DISTINCT` the `ProductID` is different on every row so all the rows are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (see  below), but this assumes that you don't care if 2 products with the same name have a different GroupID, etc. because you can't really list those unless you use a different approach (multiple queries).

```
SELECT        Product.Name
            , max(Product.ProductID) as ProductID
            , max(Product.GroupID) as GroupID
            , max(Product.GradeID) as GradeID,
            , AVG(tblReview.Grade) AS Grade
FROM            Product left Join tblReview ON Product.GroupID = tblReview.GroupID

WHERE        (Product.CategoryID = @CategoryID)

GROUP BY Product.Name

HAVING COUNT(distinct Product.Name) = 1
```

Comment: It works! I got a couple of more tables then I wrote here, do you know how efficient this method is?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked :).  As for efficiency, I'd make sure to have an index on Product.Name for starters. You can always look at the query plan also, if things are not performing as you like. You can use the Show Execution Plan option, here's an article for reference (http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx).

Comment: @dcp: you should add `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` for this to work correctly.

Comment: @Quassnoi  - Good point, I misunderstood "unique product name" to mean the returned result should consist of unique product names. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: When I add HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 or HAVING COUNT(Product.Name) = 1
, I get 0 rows returnd unfortunately.

Comment: Try it with my latest update "HAVING Count(distinct Product.Name) = 1"

Comment: Great! Please be sure to accept the answer (click the checkmark) if it solved your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Should this work for you?

```
SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.Name, Product.GroupID, Product.GradeID, 
       AVG(tblReview.Grade) AS Grade 
FROM   Product left Join tblReview ON Product.GroupID = tblReview.GroupID 
WHERE  (Product.CategoryID = @CategoryID) 
GROUP  BY Product.ProductID, Product.Name, Product.GroupID, Product.GradeID 
HAVING COUNT(Product.Name)=1
```

Comment: Nice and simple, but it doesnt filter anything, all names are displayed

Comment: So it must be the ugly way:)

SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.Name, Product.GroupID, Product.GradeID,  
       AVG(tblReview.Grade) AS Grade  
FROM   Product left Join tblReview ON Product.GroupID = tblReview.GroupID  
WHERE  Product.CategoryID = @CategoryID
AND    Product.Name in (SELECT P.Name FROM Product as P WHERE P.CategoryId = @CategoryID GROUP BY P.Name HAVING COUNT(*)=1)
GROUP  BY Product.ProductID, Product.Name, Product.GroupID, Product.GradeID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, p.GroupID, p.GradeID,
        (
        SELECT  AVG(grade)
        FROM    tblReview r
        WHERE   r.GroupID = p.GroupID
        ) AS Grade
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY productID) AS rna,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY productID DESC) AS rnd
        FROM    Product
        WHERE   CategoryID = @CategoryID
        ) p
WHERE   rna = rnd
```

Comment: I dont get it to work I get complains on cant find grade, but it looks efficient!

Comment: DataBinding: System.Data.DataRowView does not contain property Grade

Comment: Now it filters nicely, but displays products from all Categorys.

Comment: @Nicklas: did you use the query from the last update (with `WHERE   CategoryID = @CategoryID`)?

Comment: Now the Categories are right, but some products arent displayed, I dont get an error messages but I can see that some products are missing. The Products got the same kind of information.

Comment: @Niclkas: which products are not displayed?

Comment: I know it doesnt help you a lot, but it is two diffrent boards, just diffrent name. But one of them isnt displayed, really strange... I think I go for the other solution further down. Thanks alot for the time you spent on this.